# How do I leave the dance floor?

Tags: barbie-super-model

I'm [stuck](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Barbie_Super_Model_1993) in an eternal loop of dancing:

[image]

I follow the instructions perfectly, and Barbie just loops around to the start of the dance again. How do I leave the dance floor?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You leave practice room by pressing Enter, if you're playing the MS-DOS version.

Comment: +1 For posterity, did you know this off the top of your head? You answered very quickly and didn't cite a source but I can hardly believe it haha.

Comment: We were actually talking about that game in the chat and I had just beat the game myself (it was sort of a "challenge"). I went through the practice room at least 5 times myself before I realized it loops infinitely, so I started pressing buttons until I found the right one :)